# Why sed is duplicating the first added line (sending the sed output to the same file)?

Tags: linux, sed

Starting file (`/etc/crontabs/root`):

```
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day     month   weekday command
*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/15min  
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly 
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/daily  
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly 
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly
```

I want to replicate this file, remove comments... and adding the content to the same file, so I run:

```
sed '/^#/ d; s/\/etc/\/root\/etc/' /etc/crontabs/root >> /etc/crontabs/root
```

... which should remove all comments, replace `/etc` with `/etc/root`... and add the result to the same file.

**Wrong output** (please note the "extra" line starting with `*/15`):

```
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day     month   weekday command
*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly        

*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/15min     
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/hourly    
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/daily     
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/weekly    
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/monthly   

*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /root/root/etc/periodic/15min
```

**Expected/wanted output**:

```
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day     month   weekday command
*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly        

*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/15min     
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/hourly    
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/daily     
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/weekly    
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /root/etc/periodic/monthly
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't write out to the same file that you're reading from. It will read the lines that you added to the file, and continue processing them. So when it gets to the lines with `/root/etc`, it will replace the `/etc` in that, producing `/root/root/etc`. It could conceivably get stuck in an infinite loop, since it keeps extending the file and will never reach the end.

What you can do is copy the `crontab` file to a new file, then use `sed` to append to that.

```
cp /etc/crontabs/root /tmp/new_crontab
sed '/^#/ d; s/\/etc/\/root\/etc/' /etc/crontabs/root >> /tmp/new_crontab
cp /tmp/new_crontab /etc/crontabs/root
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course, it works. I was hoping for a single-line solution :)

Comment: You may be able to do it with a one-liner by using the hold space. See https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-7-examples-for-sed-hold-and-pattern-buffer-operations/

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one liner, it's fairly straightfoward using `ed`:

```
printf "%s\n" ka '1,$t' "'a,\$g/^#/d" "'a+1,\$s/\/etc/\/root\/etc/" w | ed -s /etc/crontabs/root
```

or a bit easier to read using a heredoc:

```
ed -s /etc/crontabs/root <<'EOF'
ka
1,$t
'a,$g/^#/d
'a+1,$s/\/etc/\/root\/etc/
w
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, but quite unreadable in my opinion... maybe better the multi-line solution, it's more readable.